# html hiccup, (clientwidth)

Tags: javascript, html

I log two values, the first one is a h2 tag, the second is the clientWidth of that tag

console.log(@textfield.textField[0]) = 
h2 
clientHeight: 14
clientWidth: 95
/h2

console.log(@textfield.textField[0].clientWidth) =
 0

How is this possible? I can clearly see that the clientWidth is 95, not 0

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly i need to do it on document ready AFTER the element is created and added to the DOM

Still not quite sure how it can still get the clientwidth if i log the object though... Magic